# Failure to set printer as default printer in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I cannot set my printer (HP LaserJet M1005 MFP) as the default printer in my Windows 7 laptop.

When I try to make it default the error comes like:

> operation could not be completed (error 0x00000709). double check the printer name and make sure that the printer is connected to the network

Comment: Have you tried with CAPS LOCK *off*?

Comment: Is it a network printer for sure and network accessible? Try uninstalling the printer, restarting the machine, and then reinstalling the printer and set it as the default after that. Also, consider **enabling** the [**Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon** policy setting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg486839.aspx) or applicable registry setting to do the same if your version of Windows 7 lacks `gpedit.msc`.

Comment: If this is a domain workstation attempting to connect to a deployed network printer, someone with sufficient rights should execute `gpupdate /force /wait:-1` on the computer. The error number says that the printer name is invalid, which generally means that policy hasn't properly been applied to the computer.